# Adding days to a Date with vue

Tags: javascript

I need some js code to pick 5 days after start date for my expire date
i wrote this but nothing happens:

```js
var appdatetimepickerExpireDate = new Vue({
    el: '#appdatetimepickerExpireDate',
    data: {
        date = appdatetimepickerStartDate,
        var minDate =date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 5
    },
    components: {
        DatePicker: VuePersianDatetimePicker
    }
});
```

in my console log it said Unexpected token 'var'

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Remove the var from here: *var* minDate=. Also, don't use = for a dictionary. Use :

Comment: it'll change to " Unexpected identifier" without var @kgiannakakis

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your code. Try this:

```
var date = new Date();
var appdatetimepickerExpireDate = new Vue({
     el: '#appdatetimepickerExpireDate'
      , data: {
          date: appdatetimepickerStartDate ,
          minDate: new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 5)
    }
    , components: {
        DatePicker: VuePersianDatetimePicker
    }
});
```